# How to prevent sed command overwriting the original file and output a new file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

In the `UPPER.txt` file, I need to substitute `APPLE` and `ORANGE` with non-capital `apple` and `orange`. I also need to keep the old file `UPPER.txt` as it was, and a generate a new file `lower.txt`. I am using the following commands:

```
sed 's/APPLE/apple/g' UPPER.txt > lower.txt
sed 's/ORANGE/orange/g' UPPER.txt > lower.txt
```

But the problem is that after I run the above command `UPPER.txt` and `lower.txt` become the same containing non-capital items. I want the `UPPER.txt` to remain as it was originally.

How can I keep a backup of the original file after using sed? 
Since I want to use this command in C++ using `system(command)` to operate on the files, I would like all the commands to be written in one line then I can pass it as string to system command.

Comment: what you are describing is not the expected behaviour. By default `sed` does not overwrite the original file; it writes to stdout (hence the result can be redirected using the shell operator `>` as you showed). Are you showing the exact commands used in your question?

Comment: I don't know the correct command how to do my desired described behaviour? that's why I ask for a correct command.

Comment: Do you probably have sed aliased to sed -i? Please check the output of "alias | grep sed".

Comment: @SebastianStark if that were so, the redirection would create an empty file, because `sed -i` doesn't print anything to stdout

Comment: @Zanna you're right. Then OP did not post the actual command.

Comment: Check that sed is what you expect with  which sed,   Try /usr/bin/sed for the command to see also.

Comment: No, the OP may have altered the PATH, and have a private script in it named sed before the system location.

Comment: The second command overwrites `lowercase.txt` and undoes the APPLE change from the first command. You need to chain them.

Comment: @Sepideha Please **[edit]** to add the text of `UPPECASE.txt` and `lowercase.txt` before and after running each `sed` command. If they're long, you can make a shorter input file and use that. (You needn't call your input file `UPPECASE.txt`, but either way, please do say explicitly what it is called.) Please also run `ls -l UPPECASE.txt lowercase.txt` and include the full output in your question.  Although it would be strange to have created an alias, function, or alternate external command to make in-place changes when you run `sed` without `-i`, please also show the output of `type -a sed`.

Comment: Confusing question indeed, your command should do what you want! There is definately something wrong with your sed program!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I'm not sure `sed` is broken here. The recent edit suggests the problem was [what PerlDuck said about the second command undoing the effects of the first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026963/how-to-prevent-sed-command-overwriting-the-original-file-and-output-a-new-file#comment1669237_1026963). I admit that's inconsistent with some of what the question says, but I still think it's the most likely explanation, based on the information available so far. **Sepideha**: Is that what you meant when you said the input and output files "become the same containing non-capital items"?

Comment: @EliahKagan I agree. The solution should be `sed 's/ORANGE/orange/g; s/APPLE/apple/g' UPPER.txt > lower.txt`, i.e. _both_ replacements in one `sed` command at once.

Comment: @PerlDuck This has still not been closed as unclear, apparently, and what you're presenting as the solution is at least as reasonable as the other answers, I'd say. So you might want to post that, or something like it, as an answer. **Sepideha**: Similarly, if you've solved your problem, then you can [post your own solution as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) (unless/until we end up closing this). So I suggest removing it from you question and making it an answer.  Whether or not you do, I still recommend that you edit this question with the information requested in comments.

Comment: If an answer answers your question please [accept it](/help/someone-answers) to highlight that it does. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) I took the liberty to revert the change that added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you mentioned   `sed 's/APPLE/apple/g' UPPER.txt > lower.txt` shouldn't overwrite the original `UPPER.txt`, because `sed`'s default behavior is to write to `lower.txt`. There's something else you've done that may have overwritten the original file. `sed` doesn't touch the original file unless you provide `-i` flag. For your purposes, I'd suggest first making a backup of the original file, aka just copy it.

On a side note, please be aware that `system()` call is [kinda evil](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/) and [shouldn't be used](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177),

Comment: Thanks for the answer and warning about system().
Which one is more efficient in terms of runtime and memory? 1)first making a backup and running sed- or 2) my solution in EDIT section: running sed and deleting the temp file?

Comment: @Sepideha Your solution uses 3 commands. In shell, I would do  `sed 's/ORANGE/orrange/g;  s/APPLE/apple/g' UPPER.txt > lower.txt`. This is just one command, one single process, and redirects shell output to another file. `UPPER.txt` won't be touched.  You of course can do backup as simply as copying the file, that's two commands: `cp UPPER.txt UPPER.bak;  sed 's/ORANGE/orrange/g;  s/APPLE/apple/g' UPPER.txt > lower.txt`. But if we're going to avoid `system()`, then ideal solution would be to capture output from C++ and output to new file (i.e., avoid shell and  `>` operator).

Comment: @ Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy Thanks for suggesting one-command to do all the job! great help.
I am not sure how to avoid system() in this case. You mean first opening UPPER.txt file using c++ ifstream and after processing the text, useing ofstream to write on lower.txt file/buffer?

Comment: @Sepideha Yep, that. You can use `popen` to avoid `system` See this example with running a subprocess via `popen` and capturing output :https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611186/3701431

Comment: To be honest, I would avoid `sed` altogether and do it all in C++. C++ can lowercase strings as well.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yep, that's the smartest route. OP will learn that eventually, one step at a time.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have got some misunderstandings.

The `sed` command only outputs the result in bash. It has nothing to do with original file. The `>` operator only writes the result to a file.

However, if you want, there is option `-i` which is able to edit the original file. With `-i` option comes backup suffix (optional).

```
$ cat UPPERCASE.txt 
APPLE
$ sed 's/APPLE/apple/g' UPPERCASE.txt
apple
$ sed 's/APPLE/apple/g' UPPERCASE.txt > lowercase.txt
$ cat UPPERCASE.txt 
APPLE
$ cat lowercase.txt 
apple
$ sed 's/APPLE/apple/g' -i[BACKUP] UPPERCASE.txt 
$ cat UPPERCASE.txt 
apple
$ ls
UPPERCASE.txt UPPERCASE.txt[BACKUP] lowercase.txt
```

Here, the `[BACKUP]` file is the original file.

Comment: @Zanna, I understood. Owing to this, In the first and second paragraph I wrote *this is misunderstanding*. And then I wrote *if you want* as an alternative.